# Ring theory and concept of ID

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\phi : R \to S$ be a non-zero homomorphism, where $R$, $S$ are commutative rings with unity, with unity elements $1_R$, $1_S$, respectively.  If $R$ and $S$ are integral domains, show that $\phi(1_R) = 1_S$. Show by an example that this need not hold if the integral domain condition is dropped.

Answer (score 3):

We observe that

$(\phi(1_R))^2 = \phi(1_R^2) = \phi(1_R); \tag 1$

thus

$\phi(1_R)(\phi(1_R) - 1_S) = (\phi(1_R))^2 - \phi(1_R) = 0; \tag 2$

if now $R$ and $S$ are integral domains, then this implies either

$\phi(1_R) = 0 \tag 3$

or

$\phi(1_R) - 1_S = 0; \tag 4$

we may rule out (3) since $\phi$ is a non-zero homomorphism; indeed, if (3) binds then

$\forall r \in R, \; \phi(r) = \phi(r1_R) = \phi(r)\phi(1_R) = 0; \tag 5$

that is,

$\phi = 0; \tag 6$

we thus eliminate (3) as a possibility; with

$\phi(1_R) \ne 0, \tag 7$

the fact that $S$ is an integral domain implies

$\phi(1_R) - 1_S = 0 \Longrightarrow \phi(1_R) = 1_S, \tag 8$

As a counter example take

$R = S = \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z; \tag 9$

with operations defined component wise; then it is easy to see that neither $R$ nor $S$ are integral domains; now let

$\phi:R \to S \tag{10}$

be projection onto the first factor:

$\phi(a, b) = (a, 0); \tag{11}$

then clearly

$\phi \ne 0, \tag{12}$

but

$\phi(1_R) = \phi(1, 1) = (1, 0) \ne 1_S = (1, 1). \tag{13}$